# Every time I get result from else block cant get result from if block in android

Tags: android

Every time get result from else block cant get result from if block all time show result from else block,how to solve this problem please help me.Here is my  String Url:
http://duraent.net/android_order_app/api/android/updateDoctorOtpStatus.php?otp_id=5670&e_mail=test@gmail.com

And my code:

```
private class GetDoctorResultForFinal extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Http_Doctor_Final_Submit doctorfinalrequest = new  Http_Doctor_Final_Submit();
    Context ctx;

    String latLong_url;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    private String result;

    public GetDoctorResultForFinal(View.OnClickListener _ctx, String _latong_url) {
        ctx = (Context) _ctx;
        latLong_url = _latong_url;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(Doctor_Regi.this);
        pd.setMessage("loading");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (CC7.iNa(ctx)) {

            Log.d("Request : ", "starting");


          String  result = doctorfinalrequest.makeHttp_Doctor_Final_Request(latLong_url, "GET", null);


            Log.d("Request Login attempt", result.toString());
            return result.toString();


        } else {
            return "Internet Not Available";
        }




    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
        pd.dismiss();


        try {
              Log.d("Request : 2 ", "" + result);
            if (result.equals(true)) {
                Toast.makeText(Doctor_Regi.this, "You Have Submited Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Doctor_Regi.this, DuraentMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);

           }
            else  {

                Toast.makeText(Doctor_Regi.this, "INVALID OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



           }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }












    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
  if (result.equals("true"))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: He made mistake by checking string with Boolean .

Answer (score 0):

If your method **doctorfinalrequest** return String **"true"** you have to update:

```
 if (result.equals("true"))
```

Comment: i have tried in this way that u suggest me but result is same every time getting result from else block.